# Saving data into Clob using Hibernate in Oracle 10g

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle10g, clob

I have a table with a `java.sql.Clob` column in Hibernate

**The `hbm` file:**

```
<class name="com.model.ClobModel" table="table1">
   <id name="id" column="id">
      <generator class="assigned"></generator>
  </id> 
  <property name="clobData" type="clob">
      <column name="ClobData"></column>
  </property>
```

**This is the `ClobModel`:**

```
private Integer id;
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

private Clob clobData;

public Clob getClobData() {
    return clobData;
}

public void setClobData(Clob clobData) {
    this.clobData = clobData;
}
```

**When I tried this in hibernate:**

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure("clob.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session sess = sf.openSession();

    ClobModel cb = new  ClobModel();
    cb.setId(101);
    try {
                // getClobData() method returns String, trying to convert it into java.sql.Clob and then assign it to the model
                   cb.setClobData(new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob(new ClobInsert().getClobData().toCharArray()));
    } catch (SerialException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sess.save(cb);
    sess.flush();
    System.out.println("Exit!!!");
```

**I am getting an exception:**

```
javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB
```

All the `Clob` mentioned above are of type `java.sql.Clob`.

Not sure how to convert the `String` into `java.sql.Clob`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need explicitly map the type of the field to `java.sql.Clob`.

```
<property
    name="data"
    type="java.sql.Clob"
    update="true"
    insert="true"
    column="data"
/>
```

Comment: getting this exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB`. Please have a look at the String to CLOB conversion in the above posted code (which I did using `SerialClob`. IT seems that is incorrect :(

Comment: Don't use it just use `java.sql.Clob` and hibernate will do the rest.

Comment: ok then this line will show compilation error:`cb.setClobData(new ClobInsert().getClobData());`. Here, getClobData is returning `String` but in the model, setClobData is expecting a `java.sql.Clob`. Please let me know where else to change? Please help

Comment: Use `cb.setClobData(Hibernate.createClob(new ClobInsert().getClobData()));`