# Database Lock while updating table in oracle

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate

My aplication is performing a very simple update on a table :

```
UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = 'XYZ' WHERE PK = 123
```

The problem is, when Hibernate tries to update the table like this, the table get locked with
ORA event : **SQL*Net more data from client**.

I tried to replicate the error on my local database but i couldn't.

Does Anybody know what is happening?

Database's version where the error is happening: Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

My local database's version: Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production

PS: The column being updated is a CLOB type and the OJDBC driver version is 1.4

Comment: The shadow process has received part of a call from the client process (for example, SQL*Plus, Pro*C, and JDBC) in the first network package and is waiting for more data for the call to be complete. Examples are large SQL or PL/SQL block and insert statements with large amounts of data.

Comment: A 101292 caracters lenght clob is being sent(this is the size of the value being setted in the column). Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what exactly is being sent to oracle db? I've seen something similar when Hibernate was sending very long sql command and it failed on JDBC driver.

I would suggest starting from getting latest JDBC driver version.

Comment: A 101292 caracters lenght clob is being sent(this is the size of the value being setted in the column).

Comment: How do you manage hibernate mapping? Could you send the configuration you use? Check also this: http://stephou.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/mapping-large-string-to-clob-for-oracle-with-hibernate-and-spring/

Comment: i updated my jdbc driver version to the most recent(in my case, ojdbc6) but it didnt fix my problem. I'm mapping the column(a CLOB in the database) as a String, more or less like this:                 **<property name="content" type="java.lang.String" column="LO_CONTENT" />**

Comment: Ok, try something like this: `<property name="content" type="java.sql.Clob" .. />`, probably you have similar problem as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367518/saving-data-into-clob-using-hibernate-in-oracle-10g)

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statement should be used. We should not directly assign the values. 
For example:

```
String updateSQL = UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = ? WHERE PK = ? . 
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
pstmt=dbresourceAgent.getPreparedStatement(updateSQL);
pstmt.setString(1,"XYZ");
pstmt.setString(2,"123");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```